# Annotations are not working in Groovy classes

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I have Groovy-Eclipse for Juno but my Groovy classes are not able to recognize any Annotations. I am getting `Groovy:class Translation is not an annotation in @Translation`.Or `Groovy:class Override is not an annotation in @Override` For example:

```
import somewhere.Translation
@Translation(translationContext = TranslationContext.SOMETHING)
class SOMECLASS extends SOMETHING {

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Translation {
```

Here all the annotations `@Target,@Retention` and `@interface` are compiling fine for `Translation`

 I have all the jars included in my project lib. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can we see some sample code?  Including the imports you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have your project/workspace configured for Java 1.4 or earlier.  Annotations are not being recognized since the source level doesn't allow them.

Go to Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler.   Enable project settings and set the compliance level to 1.5 or later.

Comment: It's my understanding that the Groovy wouldn't compile at all on 1.4

Comment: When I created a Groovy project in Eclipse with a 1.4 compliance level, the errors above are exactly the ones that I got.  This is the compliance level (ie- the syntax, keywords, etc) being used, not the JRE being compiled against.  Typically, they should be identical levels, but it is possible to have a compliance level of 1.4 and compile against a Java 5 JRE.

Answer (score 0):

- Did you import `import java.lang.annotation.*;` ?
- Is `translationContext` defined like a method in the `@interface` ?
- Is the correct `Translation` in the classpath, and no duplicates are there.

This code works for me in the groovy console :

```
@Translation    
class A{
def meth = { print "HzzzI" }
​}

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Translation {
} 

A a = new A();
a.meth()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. 
My Eclipse IDE underlines the annotations but the code works fine!
Just try to run it. That's it for me. Hope that's it for you as well)